# Need a range with all unicode characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

Classical Ruby implementation allows to iterate over the unicode characters:

```
('a'..'z').to_a 
# ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
('@'..'[').to_a 
# ["@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "["]
```

I need to get an array with all the unicode characters (different locales, punctuation marks, etc). How do I do that? I don't know the very first and the last characters.

Comment: “all the unicode characters” is too broad. Do you need exactly what? Letters? For instance, “★” is a unicode character. Do you need it?

Comment: @mudasobwa I need chars from english and cyrillic locales (other locales would also be useful), digits and punctuation marks.

Comment: ranges are not always continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[*32..65535].map do |e|
  e.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).tap do |char|
    char =~ /\p{Alnum}|\p{Punct}/ || raise 
  end rescue nil # rescuing both conversion and self-raised
end.compact
```

The above iterates through all the codepoints, selecting [alphanumerics and punctuation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

**NB** The approach above, while is more or less robust, failes to match diacritics, that is a part of combined characters like ç or ö.

Comment: Your code iterates through ~5% of all code points.

Comment: @一二三 Yes, so what? All the live alphabets are living there. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Unicode classifies over [100,000 code points](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:alnum=Yes:]) as alphanumeric.

Comment: @一二三 I know. I tried to provide more robust than academic answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
[*32..65535].
  pack("U*").
  encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '').
  split('')
```

> irb(main):070:0> [*32..65535].pack("U*").encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '').split('')
>   => [" ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\u007F", "\u0080", "\u0081", "\u0082", "\u0083", "\u0084", "\u0085", "\u0086", "\u0087", "\u0088",
>   ...
>   "\uFFEA", "\uFFEB", "\uFFEC", "\uFFED", "\uFFEE", "\uFFEF", "\uFFF0", "\uFFF1", "\uFFF2", "\uFFF3", "\uFFF4", "\uFFF5", "\uFFF6", "\uFFF7", "\uFFF8", "\uFFF9", "\uFFFA", "\uFFFB", "\uFFFC", "\uFFFD", "\uFFFE", "\uFFFF"]

[#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack)

[#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-encode)

[#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split)

---

(Doesn't work for all codepoints...)

```
(32..127).map {|i| i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)}
```

But replace 127 with 65535. Enjoy the scroll!

> irb(main):011:0> (32..127).map {|i| i.chr}
>   => [" ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\x7F"]

Comment: `55296.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)` ⇒ `RangeError: invalid codepoint 0xD800 in UTF-8`

Comment: hmmm... `(32..0xFFFF).map { |i| i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) rescue nil }.compact `

Comment: This helped me create a CIRCLED DIGIT conversion method. see: https://twitter.com/codybaldwin/status/1506056979776966657?s=20&t=b-yUL79OWVizHneEMgx99g

eg: (9312..9331).map {|i| i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)}[num]

Answer (score 1):

Parse through [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) (Fields described in tr44#[Property Definitions](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#UnicodeData.txt))

Pay certain attention to the ranges:

```
3400    <CJK Ideograph Extension A, First>
4DB5    <CJK Ideograph Extension A, Last>
4E00    <CJK Ideograph, First>
9FD5    <CJK Ideograph, Last>
AC00    <Hangul Syllable, First>
D7A3    <Hangul Syllable, Last>
D800    <Non Private Use High Surrogate, First>
DB7F    <Non Private Use High Surrogate, Last>
DB80    <Private Use High Surrogate, First>
DBFF    <Private Use High Surrogate, Last>
DC00    <Low Surrogate, First>
DFFF    <Low Surrogate, Last>
E000    <Private Use, First>
F8FF    <Private Use, Last>
20000   <CJK Ideograph Extension B, First>
2A6D6   <CJK Ideograph Extension B, Last>
2A700   <CJK Ideograph Extension C, First>
2B734   <CJK Ideograph Extension C, Last>
2B740   <CJK Ideograph Extension D, First>
2B81D   <CJK Ideograph Extension D, Last>
2B820   <CJK Ideograph Extension E, First>
2CEA1   <CJK Ideograph Extension E, Last>
F0000   <Plane 15 Private Use, First>
FFFFD   <Plane 15 Private Use, Last>
100000  <Plane 16 Private Use, First>
10FFFD  <Plane 16 Private Use, Last>
```

It depends on what you need the data for, on whether you iterate those ranges.